# How to hide tags select if there are no tags in my database in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to hide the tags select if there are no tags in my database so that I don't see an empty select element with no options, however, the obvious solution doesn't seem to work.

```
@if (!empty($tags))
    <label for="tags">Tag</label>
    <select name='tags'>
        @foreach($tags as $tag)
            <option value='{{$tag->id}}'>{{$tag->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a collection.

Do this:

```
if (!$tags->isEmpty()) {
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if($tags->isNotEmpty()){
    //code
}
```

This is also working.

Check [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isNotEmpty)